# Celtic modes, what modes are these?

Tags: terminology, history, modes

I know the ancient Greek modes and the Gregorian modes of the medieval era. Reading in a comment the term **Celtic modes** I wonder is there something different or special that I have missed until today?

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in the following  link there is no difference between the Celtic modes and the well known medieval modes.

But it seems there are especially 4 modes in use:

Ionian, Dorian, Mixolydian, Aeolian. See:

**Complex Tonality and the Four Celtic Modes**

https://www.banjohangout.org/archive/310602

Here’s a nice video explaining the mixolydian mode (with the typical b7) in Celtic style:

Comment: Yes. Mixolydian is perhaps the most common of these in modern “celtic-style” music by rock bands, but traditional tunes are actually much more in Ionian or Dorian.

Comment: So I shouldn't mind if someone says he was aiming Celtic mode. They are identical with the traditional modes.